# Calling scalar valued function with report parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

I've created a scalar valued function to return the maximum security classification for a set of records. Everything seems to execute fine when I define it, but when I try to call it, I'm told I need to declare the scalar variable "@START" and that The multi-part identifier "innovator.GetMaxSecurityTPSummary(@STATE,  @START, @END)" could not be bound. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4104)

The function:

```
 set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

Alter FUNCTION [innovator].[GetMaxSecurityTPSummary] 
(
    @State As varchar, @START As varchar, @END As varchar
)
RETURNS varchar(2048)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @MaxSecurity varchar(2048)
    SET @MaxSecurity = '';

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    select @MaxSecurity =  (SELECT     TOP (1) SECURITY_CLASSIFICATION
                            FROM          innovator.TP AS tp1
                            WHERE      (IS_CURRENT = 1) AND (CREATED_ON >= CONVERT(datetime, @START, 104)) AND (CREATED_ON <= CONVERT(datetime, @END, 104)) 
                                                   AND (STATE = 'Closed') AND (@STATE = 'Closed') OR
                                                   (IS_CURRENT = 1) AND (CREATED_ON >= CONVERT(datetime, @START, 104)) AND (CREATED_ON <= CONVERT(datetime, @END, 104)) 
                                                   AND (STATE <> 'Closed') AND (@STATE = 'Open')
                            ORDER BY (CASE SECURITY_CLASSIFICATION WHEN 'Unclassified' THEN 1 WHEN 'Protected A' THEN 2 WHEN 'Protected B' THEN 3 WHEN 'Protected C'
                                                    THEN 4 WHEN 'Classified' THEN 5 WHEN 'Secret' THEN 6 WHEN 'Top Secret' THEN 7 ELSE 0 END) DESC) 


    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @MaxSecurity;

END
```

The query calling the function:

```
    SELECT     TP_ID, innovator.[GetMaxSecurityTPSummary(@STATE,  @START, @END)] AS SecurityMax
FROM         innovator.TP AS tp
WHERE     (IS_CURRENT = 1) AND (CREATED_ON >= CONVERT(datetime, @START, 104)) AND (CREATED_ON <= CONVERT(datetime, @END, 104)) AND 
                      (STATE = 'Closed') AND (@STATE = 'Closed') OR
                      (IS_CURRENT = 1) AND (CREATED_ON >= CONVERT(datetime, @START, 104)) AND (CREATED_ON <= CONVERT(datetime, @END, 104)) AND 
                      (STATE <> 'Closed') AND (@STATE = 'Open')
UNION
SELECT     NULL AS Expr1, 'N/A' AS Expr2
WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT     id
                            FROM          innovator.TP AS tp1
                            WHERE      (IS_CURRENT = 1) AND (CREATED_ON >= CONVERT(datetime, @START, 104)) AND (CREATED_ON <= CONVERT(datetime, @END, 104)) 
                                                   AND (STATE = 'Closed') AND (@STATE = 'Closed') OR
                                                   (IS_CURRENT = 1) AND (CREATED_ON >= CONVERT(datetime, @START, 104)) AND (CREATED_ON <= CONVERT(datetime, @END, 104)) 
                                                   AND (STATE <> 'Closed') AND (@STATE = 'Open')))
```

Free bag of cheesies for anyone who can help (and by bag of cheesies I mean my gratitude)

Comment: How are you passing values to `@STATE`, `@START`, and `@END` in your query? Do you have them declared at all?

Comment: The query is used inside a report within visual studio, so the values for @STATE, etc. are defined by the user (as report parameters), so they are declared. Using those (@STATE, etc.) in any other way but the above function call causes no problems whatsoever.

The purpose of the order by and selecting only the top record gets me only the highest security classification of all records contained in the set.

Comment: Did you map the parameters in reporting services. It looks parameters are not mapped.

Comment: Yes I did. I figured it out... see answer. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the square brackets from the function call allowed it to go through. I had to modify the function a bit after that for other reasons, but it's working now.

It's always something foolish.

Can't believe I didn't think to try that sooner.